# How could I create a dropdown menu using HTML & CSS w/o referencing two files

Tags: html, css, widget

**Hello,**

I was wondering if there was a way to create a **drop down menu** using HTML & CSS at once without having two separate files to reference. I use a website called Experience Builder which is owned and operated by ESRI.

It allows the user to make their own web pages and link data to widgets that the user can put in the page. However, it's a bit limited on the creativity front. I would like to see a drop down menu in one of my pages.

There is an "embed" widget. I am able to insert code into this widget. However, I can't reference files. So if I wanted to create something that uses CSS & HTML I'd need to combine them into one big block of code.

I would greatly appreciate any help w/ this task. I'm starting to take courses on this topic, but I'm not that experienced yet. It doesn't need to be anything fancy and if I have the framework I know enough to modify it.

Even if someone would have a resource that they could link to that I could read and figure it out I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you not just use a `<style></style>` tag somewhere in the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

In HTML you can include a `<style></style>` tag where you can then input whatever CSS you want. Take a look at the snippet below, the CSS is in the style tag in the HTML

```html
<style>
  .divs {
    height: 3rem;
    width: 3rem;
  }

  #div1 { background: red }
  #div2 { background: blue }
  #div3 { background: green }
</style>

<div class="divs" id="div1">
</div>

<div class="divs" id="div2">
</div>

<div class="divs" id="div3">
</div>
```